# Has anyone studied a transport equation of this form?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, asymptotics

Let $L\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb R$ satisfy
$$
  \frac{\partial L}{\partial t} (x,t) = \max\left\{ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2} \right\}
$$
with some initial data $L(x,0) = L_0(x)$. I'm looking for results about this equation.

Comment: Rescaling time, $\tau = \theta t$, the equation becomes $\partial L/\partial \tau = \max\{\partial L/\partial x_1,\partial L/\partial x_2\}$; so you can assume that $\theta=1$.

Comment: Of course, that's true, thanks. I've changed the question and removed the $\theta$ from it.